# Windows 8 says database.db doesn't exist, but my ramaze app says it does 8 (works on Windows 7)

Tags: ruby, ramaze

I think the images explain enough. This is a very weird bug. It works on my Windows 7 laptop but not my Windows 8 one.

Windows says that database.db doesn't exist but my ramaze app thinks it does. The app writes to the database, but I cannot view the database in sqlitespy as the file "does not exist".

[image: ghost database]
[image: somehow i can edit but the sqlite file doesn't exist]

How can I make Windows recognise the database.db file?

Comment: I've got it to show hidden files.

Comment: You might be looking in the wrong place. The "../" in ../database.db tells us that the file exists in a parent directory.

Comment: It's not their either. http://imgur.com/DQpibJE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by setting the compatibility mode for `bin/ruby.exe` to Windows 7.